# Effects of children's exposure to video-games

Tags: mental-health, dyslexia-dyslexic

An example of videogame which made parents to be worried is [Gran Theft Auto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto#Titles): a game in which participants gain scores by making sex with a prostitute or by killing people. [Some studies](https://www.aacap.org/aacap/families_and_youth/facts_for_families/FFF-Guide/Children-and-Video-Games-Playing-with-Violence-091.aspx) reveal that on average, girls spend more than 1 hour per day playing videogames and boys spend more than 2 hours.

```
Additionally a study led by Dill & Dill (1998) suggests that an extended 
exposure to 
videogames violence increases aggressive behavior and other aggression-
related phenomena. Clear effects on social and emotional development.
```

*I was wondering whether any studies have been done that investigate the effect of videogames on cognitive development*, **furthermore if to play to videogames could be considered as a risk factor for dyslexia.**

References

[Dill & Dill, 1998](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359178997000013)

Comment: This is a good question, though I would refine the last sentence to define what you mean by cognitive development - if you want specifically disorders similar to dyslexia, then it's an easier to answer question, whereas general cognitive development is vast.  But I actually think you have a higher likelihood of receiving replies at CogSci SE.  Might check them out!

Comment: That description on GTA is not really accurate though. You don't "gain scores" by performing those actions, especially not by having sex with a prostitute. It's not even clear what you mean by "scores". I'm not sure if you have played the game yourself. Also, GTA as a whole is really intended as a (brilliant) satire of the American society, but of course the kids with their knowledge might be unable to perceive that and take in some of the elements of the game at their face value, which might be bad.

Comment: But yeah, this might be a complicated subject. Some studies suggested that some games would actually help cognitive development as well as serve as some kind of treatment for cognitive disorders. But some other studies are negative. Anyways, I don't think dyslexia would be a particular concern in terms of games. Gaming is so widespread but kids nowadays don't suddenly become more dyslexic than kids before. People I know who gamed a lot growing up still studied very well, got top grades and got admitted to top universities. Dyslexia probably has causes other than gaming.

Comment: If games are so bad and demonic as some conservatives like to make them out to be then they'd have long evoked much greater backlash from the parents and be banned, etc. This has not happened. I don't think they're fundamentally different from forms of entertainment of previous eras such as outdoor games, chess or TV either. It's just entertainment in a new form. The older generation also panicked a lot when TV first came out. I think the generation growing up watching TV turned out just fine.

Comment: Another factor why it might not have much to do with dyslexia is that actually if you have played some AAA games you'd know well that there's actually much more reading involved in those games than in say TVs and movies, where there's literally zero reading or active participation required on the viewer's part. Games are not like that. They require the player to actively solve challenges most of the time, albeit admittedly relatively shallow/casual ones.

Comment: You could take a look in google scholar.  I can think of several aspects of this -- direct effects of game play; game play encouraging certain ways of using the brain that might not build capacity for, for example, problem solving skills; and the amount of time spent on game play possibly interfering with doing other things that demonstrably increase cognitive ability.

Comment: A very recent study from France is pointing the fact that dislexya might be a trouble with the eyes, where they're perfectly aligned (no eye director) which make the brain having troubles to select the right image. However it is currently not now if this concern all forms of dislexya. And for studies about violences from video games, they're tons saying that it doesn't now and they're as objective as those studies that want to show you that woman can't do some [insert stereotype activity] that man properly do (or the opposite).